# Color guidelines for blue and orange website

Tags: buttons, color-scheme, calendar

What would be the good choice of colors to put on my calendar day buttons so that the user will easily identify what is done, skip or ongoing. For now I use the `orange as default button color`, `blue color for the ongoing`, `grey for done` and `skip is grayed orange`. I will appreciate your inputs. Thanks!

As of now this is what I come up with:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a img or something so that we can see it.

Comment: As evidenced by the answers below, what you will get here will be almost entirely opinion based rather than based on any testable grounds. However,  I can tell you that using colour alone for indication of status or hierarchy is bad practice - use a symbol, shape, or pattern along with your colour so that users with low vision or colourblindness are not left out. If you're stuck on using orange in particular, you should also check the contrast ratio with the text and background to make sure that it's going to be visible for ALL users.

Comment: @neophyte, I added a sample image.

Comment: @AndrewMartin, Yes I know that. That's why I need some help to suggest any color so that I can play with. Sorry that the question is basically an opinion base.

Comment: @claudios, I can see from your image that you're still only using colour - If users cannot distinguish between orange and blue they will not be able to decipher which are "missed" and which are "ongoing". Again: use a symbol, shape, or pattern along with your colour. The colour you use should be largely irrelevant. As for contrast, there are plenty of free colour contrast measurement tools out there, either as stand alone or as plugins for popular image editing tools. My personal preference is this: https://www.paciellogroup.com/resources/contrastanalyser/ (also shows colourblind results)

Answer (score 1):

I think for ongoing you should use some strong shade of orange- red.

Reason: red depicts importance so as your website is orange in I would suggest reddish orange.

As blue is a positive color so blue for done.

You can use grayed orange for skip  and grey button for default.